# Can't use find() with two-dimensional array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, find

I've got a problem with using find on 2-dimensional arrays. Every time I try to perform such find, I get an ununderstandable error

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int st[200*1000][2];
int si[200*1000][2];

int main() {
    if (find(si, si+200000, true) == si+200000){
        //do something
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < ileSt; j++){
        for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++){
            if (find(st[j], st[j]+2, si[znakSi][k]) != st[j]+2){
                //do another thing
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algobase.h:71:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/bits/char_traits.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ios:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/5/iostream:39,
                 from prog.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/predefined_ops.h: In instantiation of 'bool __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<_Value>::operator()(_Iterator) [with _Iterator = int (*)[2]; _Value = const bool]':
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h:120:14:   required from '_RandomAccessIterator std::__find_if(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Predicate, std::random_access_iterator_tag) [with _RandomAccessIterator = int (*)[2]; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<const bool>]'
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h:161:23:   required from '_Iterator std::__find_if(_Iterator, _Iterator, _Predicate) [with _Iterator = int (*)[2]; _Predicate = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_equals_val<const bool>]'
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_algo.h:3790:28:   required from '_IIter std::find(_IIter, _IIter, const _Tp&) [with _IIter = int (*)[2]; _Tp = bool]'
prog.cpp:19:31:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/predefined_ops.h:194:17: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
  { return *__it == _M_value; }
                 ^
```

Also, it's my first question, so if you think it could be written better, feel free to edit it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of `si[n]` is an `int[2]`, not an `int` or a `bool`. Therefore you cannot perform `find` on `si`, which is an array of `int[2]`, for the value `true`, which is a `bool` (or `int` with implicit conversion). The error message tells you basically the same thing:

```
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/predefined_ops.h:194:17: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
```

Instead, the following code should allow you to find *any* `true` (i.e. 1) in the 2-D array:

```
int* const si_begin = &si[0][0];
int* const si_end = &si[200*1000][0];
if (find(si_begin, si_end, true) == si_end){
  //do something
}
```

If your intention was to find `true` only in the 1st element of the inner array, then like Swift suggested in the comment, it's better off using a custom loop for the find. `std::find()` is only used for finding matching element in a 1-D array.

Comment: he probably wanted to check every first element of subarray, so that code wouldn't work. why not to use just for() loops and create own find subroutine? std::find good only for single-dimensional cases. And should be (int)true

Comment: @Swift: Thanks. It wasn't clear what his intention was, but you could be right. Edited to incorporate your comments.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite it using direct addressing to the 2d array elements.
For example:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < ileSt; j++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++)
    {
        if (find(&st[j][0], &st[j][0] + 2, si[znakSi][k]) != &st[j][0] + 2 )
        {
            //do another thing
        }
    }
}
```

Or using std::begin to get row address for your array

```
find(std::begin(st[j]), std::begin(st[j]) + 2, si[znakSi][k]) != std::begin(st[j]) + 2
```

Comment: If I use `std::begin`, I get a `'begin' is not a member of 'std'` error, and if I use just `begin`, I get a `'begin' was not declared in this scope` error.

Comment: std::begin has been provided since C++11

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to address the memory outside the array and you must use a pointer to single element of array to address multidimensional array as a single dimensional one.

Pointers `si` and `st` have  type of `int*[2]` not `int*`, so `(si+1)` points at 3rd int (a second sub-array of `int*[2]` type), `(si+200000)` points at 400001th int in that array. Compiler tries to specialize find() template, assuming that you gave it proper iterator, follows that semantic and works in wrong way... Pointer to a trivial type can be an iterator, pointer to array apparently fails. You should use a pointer to `int*` or `char*` (from C++11 standard's definition only `char*` got defined results, but all existing compilers follow the C99 behavior), e.g. cast si:

```
int *pSi = (int*)si;
```

Second, you try to compare a boolean(true) constant to an integer. Template requres 3rd parameter to be of same type as the iterator's target. if you use int* then it is int. Either cast that explicitly or reconsiders if that's what you actually want to do there.